# C code to decipher code

Tags: c, string

I want to write a program which receives an encoded string, and prints the decoded string.
The number after each word is the “left shift” number used to encode that word.

for instant:

> Please insert the coded string
>
> uif1hdjoh3has0ncpfgf2
>
> The decoded string is:
>
> the eagle has landed

I cant figure out why its not working:
when i switch:

```
solved_lett=(spaced_string[k]-factors[j]-'0'
```

to:

```
solved_lett=(spaced_string[k]+factors[j]-'0'
```

its working fine (but i want to move the letters to the left and not to the right).

and, what the best way to make it work in circle, means

> a1

will be

> z

```
include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
char string[101]={0}, spaced_string[101]={0}, factors[101]={0}, solved_str[101]={0}, solved_lett;
int  i=0, j=0, k=0;

printf("Please insert the coded string\n");
scanf("%s",string);
for (i=0; i<101;i++ ) {
    if (string[i]=='\0') {
        break;
    }
    if ((string[i]>96)&&(string[i]<123)) {
       spaced_string[i]=string[i];
    } else {
        spaced_string[i]=32;
        factors[j]=string[i];
        j++;
    }
   
}
k=0;
j=0;
for (k=0; k<i; k++) {
    if (spaced_string==0) {
        break;
    }
    if (spaced_string[k]!=32) {
        solved_lett=(spaced_string[k]-factors[j]-'0');
        solved_str[k]=solved_lett;
    }
    else  {
        j++;
        solved_str[k]=32;
    }
}


printf("%s",solved_str);

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to substract the number in `factors` from `spaced_string`

```
solved_lett = spaced_string[k] - (factors[j] - '0');
```

This way you first convert factors to an int value and then reduce it to the actual char value.
Now you can test if the result is too small to be a valid character:

```
if (solved_lett < 'a')
  solved_lett += 26;
```

If you use capital letters as well, you need to check for them, too

Answer (score 0):

In another approach, instead of doing `factors[j] - '0'`, you can use `atoi()`. I think that will serve the same purpose and increase readability.

Also, you might want to add a `\0` at the end of the final `char array` if you want to use that as a string, in case.

Please check the below code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
        char string[101]={0}, spaced_string[101]={0}, factors[101]={0}, solved_str[101]={0}, solved_lett;
        int  i=0, j=0, k=0;

        printf("Please insert the coded string\n");
        scanf("%s",string);
        for (i=0; i<101;i++) {
                if (string[i]=='\0') {
                        break;
                }
                if ((string[i]>96)&&(string[i]<123)) {
                        spaced_string[i]=string[i];
                } else {
                        spaced_string[i]=32;
                        factors[j]=atoi(&string[i]); //save as int
                        j++;
                }

        }
        k=0;
        j=0;
        for (k=0; k<i; k++) {
                if (spaced_string==0) {
                        break;
                }
                if (spaced_string[k]!=32) {
                        solved_lett=(spaced_string[k]-factors[j]);//use directly
                        solved_str[k]=solved_lett;
                }
                else  {
                        j++;
                        solved_str[k]=32;
                }
        }

        solved_str[k]=0;//required to print as a string

        printf("Decoded is %s\n", solved_str);

        return 0;
}
```

#### EDIT

In the above case, you should also incorporate a check for the valid value of the entered `number`. For example, you should check the value of `string[i]` to reside between 48 and 57 (`ASCII` 0-9), inclusive and if it is success, then only you should proceed to use `atoi()`.